# Ruby Else never reach in IF ELSE statement

Tags: ruby

I have what I would think would be a pretty straightforward piece of code.  However, the "else"   The following code is not mine exactly, but it illustrates the structuring of blocks:

```
adHoc = true

if blah...
   adHoc = false
end

if blah...

   if adHoc
      my_logger.info("REACHED WHENEVER ADHOC IS TRUE")
   else 
      my_logger.info("NEVER REACHED")
   end

end
```

How come the else part is never reached?

Thank you.

Comment: Because `blah` is always false when `adHoc` is false?

Comment: what's in the first blah... ? the adHoc = false is probably never called.

Comment: What exactly are you seeing in your log? Why you've decided that only else part is never reached? Have you seen _REACHED WHENEVER ADHOC IS TRUE_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Else never reached in IF ELSE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345464/ruby-else-never-reached-in-if-else-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Trace through the possibilities, there are only 4 cases:

1. blah... is true on both calls.
2. blah... is false on both calls
3. blah... is true on the first and false on the second
4. blah... is false on the first and true on the second.

Scenario 1.

> **blah** is *true*.  **adhoc** is set to *false*.  NEVER REACHED is logged.

Scenario 2.

> **blah** is *false*, **adHoc** is set to *true*.   Nothing is logged here.

Scenario 3.

> **blah** is *true*, **adHoc** is set to *false*.  Nothing is logged because the 2nd blah is false.

Scenario 4.

> **blah** is *false*, **adHoc** is set to *true*.
>   The second call to blah is true and "REACHED WHENEVER ADHOC IS TRUE" is logged.

---

**As you can see, the only way for the "REACHED WHENEVER ADHOC IS TRUE" to be displayed is in Scenario 4 where blah... changes from false to true between calls.**

---

One possibility for blah... for scenarios 3 or 4 is:

> ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_NODE].odd?